# Как понять отправку сообщения в ООП?

Tags: javascript, ооп

Здравствуйте!
 На данный момент изучаю ООП и столкнулся с непониманием фразы
 "отправка сообщения".

Вот очень упрощенное изложение:
 Допустим у нас есть два класса **X** и **Y**. В классе **X** есть метод **getData** который возвращает какие-то данные. В классе **Y** есть
 метод **handleData** который обрабатывает данные и возвращает новые. 
Вот код:

```
class X {
    getData() {
        return 'some data';
    }
 }
 class Y {
    handleData(data) {
        return data + 'some operation on data';
    }
 }
// создаём объекты
const x = new X();
const y = new Y();
// вызываем методы
let data = x.getData();
let handledData = y.handleData(data);
```

И вот собственно вопрос: 
Можно ли сказать исходя из кода выше что объект **y** посылает сообщение объекту **x** т.к. он использует данные из объекта **x**?

Или же я заблуждаюсь и термин 'посылать сообщение' в ООП это если бы внутри объекта y использовался бы объект **x** т.е. реализация была бы такой:

```
class X {
    getData() {
        return 'some data';
    }
 }
 class Y {
    constructor() {
        this._x = new X();
    }
    handleData() {
        let data = this._x.getData();
        return data + 'some operation on data';
    }
 }
// создаём объект
const y = new Y();

// вызываем метод
let handledData = y.handleData();
```

Comment: связанный вопрос [What are the key differences between OO in Smalltalk and Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3102695/2881286) и еще один [what is message passing in OO?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/140602)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В первом варианте объект `х` просто возвращает данные. Он никак не взаимодействует с объектом `у`. Он вообще ничего о нем не знает, более того он с ним взаимодействует через глобальную переменную `data`. Так же как и `y` никак не взаимодействует с `х`. он просто на вход своего метода получает какие то данные хранящиеся в глобальной переменной `data` (непонятно как туда попавшие). Этот метод плох тем что для обработки информации используется посредник в виде переменной в глобальной области видимости.

Во втором варианте у вас уже объекты классов таки взаимодействуют между собой но то что вы написали называется композиция и это не хорошо, я бы даже сказал что это плохо и вот почему. Представим что в один прекрасный момент Вы решите переписать класс Y (даже хотя бы переименовать) все классы у которых ваш `Y` используется явнsм образом придется переписывать. Тогда как если использовать агрегацию ( а если копнуть глубже то паттерн "внедрение зависимостей") то ваш второй пример можно переписать как то так

```
class X {
    getData() {
        return 'some data';
    }
 }
 class Y {
    constructor(dataSource) {
        this._x = dataSource;
    }
    handleData() {
        let data = this._x.getData();
        return data + 'some operation on data';
    }
 }
// создаём объект
const y = new Y(new X);

// вызываем метод
let handledData = y.handleData();
```

В итоге вы передаете в ваш `Y` объект который предполагаемо имеет метод `getData`. Тоесть вы можете в любой момент на этапе

```
const y = new Y(new X);
```

подменить `X` хоть `Z` хоть `W` лишm бы там был метод `getData`.

Но давайте представим что мы можем заранее не знать кому потребуются данные из метода `getData` класса `X` ...

На закуску чтобы вот совсем для ваших нужд - `объект y посылает сообщение объекту x` посмотрите на паттерн `odserver`

```js
class X {
  constructor () {
    this.subscribers = []
  }
  subscribe (subscriber) {
    this.subscribers.push(subscriber)
  }
  releaseData() {
    this.subscribers.forEach(subscriber => subscriber.handleData('some data'));
  }
}
class Y {
  handleData(data) {
    console.log(data + 'some operation on data in Y');
  }
}

// создаём источника данных
const x = new X();
// создаем подписчика
const y = new Y();
// подписываемся на событие генерации данных
x.subscribe(y);
// инициируем отправку данных и получаем их в `y`
x.releaseData()
```